# Magento2 solution specialist exam: What is the passing score of and study material for that

Tags: magento2, certification

I Just come to know that Magento announces first certification exam in `Magento2` version.

After reading in this page https://u.magento.com/certified-magento2-solution-specialist

I have some question about the exam.

What is the number of question asked in an exam (I think 150 But need to confirm)?

What is the passing score for this exam?

what is study material useful for this exam?

and last, except `Free study Guide` any other study material available for this exam.

Are there any passing criteria for `EE edition` just like we have in `M1 Developer Plus Exam` ?

Comment: We just published an annotated study guide for the exam (110 pages): https://swiftotter.com/technical/magento-2-certified-solution-specialist-exam-study-guide. We also have a sample practice test with 36 questions: https://swiftotter.com/technical/magento-2-certified-solution-specialist-practice-test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Now Onwards There are 75 Questions in exam For Magento 2 Solution Specialist

**This is for beta exam**

And Today I got mail from Magento team that contain's below text

> There are 75 questions with a passing score is 53/ 70 with 5 unscored
> questions.

**after beta this is the passing score.**

Magento 2 Certified Solutions Specialist exam: 67% or higher

Source :
https://magento-u-support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011824472-What-is-a-passing-score-for-the-certification-exams-

Comment: This is wrong answer. Please correct it.

Comment: @SudhanshuBajaj Thanks to notify me, answer updated

Answer (score 2):

you can get study course at [Offical Magento Site](https://u.magento.com/certified-magento2-solution-specialist#.XdJ3bFczaUk)

total Question will be 60, breakdown as below:

- Ecommerce – 08 Questions
- Magento Architecture – 13 Questions
- Magento Admin and StoreFront – 18 Questions
- Business and Applications– 08 Questions
- Catalog – 13 Questions

Pass Percentage = 67 or above

Answer (score 1):

**MAGENTO 2 CERTIFIED SOLUTION SPECIALIST (BETA EXAM)** is from **August 14th to August 25th, 2017**

- This Beta exam will be limited to 200 registrants.
- exam at a discounted rate of $130
- 150 Multiple Choice items/180 minutes to complete the exam
- Passing score and criteria is still not known. May be based on the 200 registrants they will decide some cut-off.
- I have applied for the exam and I am following the [PDF](https://magento-u.magento.com/magento-u/downloads/M2%20MCSS%20Cert%20Exam%20BETA%20Study%20Guide.pdf) provided by them. Go through Code base of CE and EE, Access the admin and its flow.
- All questions are valid for Magento Community Edition (2.0.x/2.1.x) and Magento Enterprise Edition (2..0.x/2.1.x).

Register fast as this Beta exam will be limited to 200 registrants.

**Link** : https://u.magento.com/certification-magento2-solution-specialist-1

Comment: This is the same detail they have mentioned in their site, nothing new .

Comment: I have replied for the possibilities also....

Answer (score 1):

Nothing have been decided yet.

And the results of the exam are not immidiately shown (it will take from 4 to 6 weeks to annonce the results)

So the answer is that nobody nows, the only sure thing is that from the 150 there will be some question to be removed without impacting scores.

And do not forget that one of the purposes of this beta exam is to decide a pertinent pass score and other details based on the 200 candidates results.

**UPDATE :** 
After beta exam, the theshold is set 75.76 so may be it should be the exams passing score.

Answer (score 1):

The passing score for the beta exam is little above 75%. I think it will be very similar with the normal exam.

Answer (score 1):

The passing score for the beta exam was unknown at the time. Later the passing score was set to 75.76% for the beta exam. Most probably they will keep this threshold.