# What kind of concepts and questions asked in Magento Solution Specialist Certification?

Tags: magento2.3, certification

**What Magento looks for in candidate who clears the exam ?**

> Like a perspective from a **Magento Business Model** to **Client's
>   requirement gathering**.

**EDIT**

This is not duplicate of this **[question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188325/magento2-solution-specialist-exam-what-is-the-passing-score-of-and-study-materi)** or any other question I have done **research** and I didn't find any stratified answer that's why I asked a new question, so please read the question's description carefully.

**I want to know from Business perspective what Magento looks in to candidate of Solution specialist on behalf of Customer.**

Comment: NO, IT'S NOT. I want to know from Business perspective what Magento looks in to candidate of Solution specialist on behalf of Customer.

Comment: what are the responsibilities   of Magento Solution specialist

Comment: Yes @ prabhakaran7 thanks ! 
Yes,from client's perspective and as well as a Project coordinator. Because they are non-technical right ?

Comment: Like a scenarios with any example will be helpful @prabhakaran7

Comment: @lizcap are you completed magento solution specialist certification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Industry Knowledge**

> Just like development expertise, Magento industry expertize is equally
>   important.

- Statistic of Previous projects about their challenges, frameworks,
  and knowledge of the industry, with different Magento versions Enterprise, Go, and Community.
- Each Magento versions features, functions and frameworks, and how to
  use them.
- Technical know-how should be your top priority. Howbeit, many other
  aspects matter when you want to make an important hiring.

[image]

**MAGENTO 2 SOLUTION SPECIALIST OVERVIEW**

- A Magento 2 Solution Specialist is an expert user of the Magento 2
  ecommerce platform.
- It is designed for those who can efficiently align business
  objectives with Magento 2 functionality, optimize use of native
  features, and **avoid unnecessary customization**.
- Areas of knowledge include eCommerce, Magento Architecture, Magento
  Admin & Storefront, Business & Applications, and Catalog.
- Design and manage a Magento project from a business perspective
- Determine how to meet requirements **with native configurations and
  when customization is necessary**
- **Understand what makes ecommerce work**
- Act as an arbiter between the technical and business team members
  which also requires an understanding of their knowledge

**References**

- https://u.magento.com/certified-magento2-solution-specialist#.XPKjNNQzbtQ
- https://serverguy.com/magento/how-to-hire-magento-developer/